# Deriving the Unit-Height Impulse Function from Limit of Difference of Heaviside Functions

Tags: limits, measure-theory, step-function

The unit-height impulse function can be defined as

$
I(x)=\begin{cases} 1,& \text{if } x = 0 \\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

We can define the Heaviside Step Function as

$
H(x)=\begin{cases} 0,& \text{if } x < 0 \\
    1,              & \text{if } x > 0
\end{cases}$

(There are variants to this $H(x)$, such as the right-continuous Heaviside Step Function, which may possibly be more appropriate to choose for the question below.)

I am wondering, is it correct to say:

$I(x) = \lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0}(H(x- \Delta) - H(x+\Delta))$

or does

$\lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0}(H(x- \Delta) - H(x+\Delta)) = 0 \text{, for all } x$, including $x=0$?

Note, I am not talking about inside an integral, where $I(x)$ is equivalent to the function that is equal to zero for all $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation of $I(x) = \lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0}(H(x- \Delta) - H(x+\Delta))$ must in fact be$$I(x) = \lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0^-}(H(x- \Delta) - H(x+\Delta))$$this is because $H(-\Delta)=1+H(\Delta)=0$ for $\Delta<0$ and as long as $\Delta\to 0^-$ we have $\Delta\ne 0$.

For $x\ne 0$, we have $$(x-\Delta)(x+\Delta)=x^2-\Delta^2>0$$ for sufficiently small $|\Delta|$. So what does this lead to?

Comment: Could you please tell me what does $\lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0^-}$ mean? Does it mean approaching $0$ from the negative side or does it mean approaching $0$, but never being equal to zero? The latter is what I thought $\lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0}$ meant.

Comment: Sure! This means that $\Delta$ tends to $0$ from below, or from negative numbers, e.g.$$-0.1,-0.01,-0.001,-0.0001,-0.00001,\cdots\to 0$$

Comment: Thank you!So, with $\lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0}$ we have $\Delta$ never is set equal to exactly $0$? Hence, I would think that there would remain an interval, of measure $0$, at $x=0$, where where the difference would equal to $1$. Sorry for the problems typing...

Comment: Yes your implication is correct and for the typo, I didn't notice anything wrong.

Comment: So, then one can simply say: $I(x) = \lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0}(H(x- \Delta) - H(x+\Delta))$ or is the $0^-$ still needed in the limit?

Comment: For $x\n 0$ it does not matter since $x$ is dominant against $\Delta$ . For $x=0$, if $\Delta\to 0^+$ the limit equals $-1$ instead of $1$.